# How can I determine the channels I need to enable in order to install a conda package?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

For instance, say I want to install the bioconda package `gapfiller`.

```sh
conda new -n gapfiller -c bioconda -c conda-forge gapfiller
```

If I run the above command, I get the following error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - boost[version='>=1.57.0,<1.57.1.0a0']

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
```

At this point, what is the next step I should take to determine which channel I need to start including?

I've tried looking at the [`meta.yml` for the package](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/gapfiller), but that only lists the *packages* that `gapfiller` depends on, not the channels that they can be found in. I've also tried `conda search boost`, but of course that only returns (incompatible) results in my current channels, it doesn't tell me how to find new channels:

```sh
$ conda search boost
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
boost                         1.65.1          py27_4  pkgs/main           
boost                         1.65.1  py27h0eb07c9_3  pkgs/main           
boost                         1.65.1          py35_4  pkgs/main           
boost                         1.65.1  py35heb9229b_3  pkgs/main           
boost                         1.65.1          py36_4  pkgs/main           
boost                         1.65.1  py36hfaba7b9_3  pkgs/main           
boost                         1.67.0          py27_4  pkgs/main           
boost                         1.67.0          py35_4  pkgs/main           
boost                         1.67.0          py36_4  pkgs/main           
boost                         1.67.0          py37_4  pkgs/main           
boost                         1.71.0          py38_0  pkgs/main
```

How can I determine the right channel to use to solve a `PackagesNotFoundError`?

Comment: Search on anaconda.org, that will search all the channels. You can also specify a version to search for from within your current channels, or you can specify `-c` to `conda search`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often, when it comes to old package versions, they got relegated to [the **free** channel which was taken off the **defaults** metachannel last year](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/why-we-removed-the-free-channel-in-conda-4-7). There are a few ways to add it back in (e.g., config setting `restore_free_channel` or env variable `CONDA_RESTORE_FREE_CHANNEL`), but a straightforward *ad hoc* solution is to include it as a one of the channels:

```
conda install -c free ...
```

For `boost=1.57` on **linux-64** platform, I see

```
conda search -c free boost=1.57[subdir='linux-64']
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
boost                         1.57.0               0  free                
boost                         1.57.0               1  free                
boost                         1.57.0               4  free
```

Comment: Hmm well in this case you're correct. But is this a general solution?

Comment: @Migwell general? No, not really - at least nothing programmatic. As darthbith mentioned, Anaconda.org let's you search for packages, and that includes user channels (i.e., use-at-your-own-risk). Generally, you only want to use channels you trust. Most packages are on either **defaults** or **conda-forge** (or for me **bioconda**), with some older ones relegated to **free**, plus an occasional organization channel, e.g., **pytorch** for bleed-edge releases.